# Equivalence of condition for Lebesgue-measurability

Tags: measure-theory

We had a proof in lecture, that showed a bunch of equivalences for Lebesgue-measurability. I have a problem understanding the following implication, where the professor said the reasoning was "trivial".

> Let $A\subseteq\mathbb{R^n}$. If there exists $B\in F_\sigma$ such that $\lambda_n^*((A\setminus B)\cup(B\setminus A))=0$ then $A$ is Lebesgue-measurable. $F_\sigma$ denotes sets that are a countable union of closed sets, $\lambda_n^*$ is the $n$-dimensional Lebesgue outer measure.

Can anyone jump start me as to why this is "trivial"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
A=(B\setminus(B\setminus A))\cup(A\setminus B).
$$
The rest should be more trivial.

Comment: I'm still stuck. How do I apply this?

Comment: $B$, $B\setminus A$ and $A\setminus B$ are measurable.